# Change my location IP

Tags: java

Is there any utility or class in java by which I can change my machine IP address. Like I am sitting in California and shows the users that I am actually sitting in London.

Comment: Imagine the consequences if IP addresses were generally spoofable... you can use a [proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) to simulate appearing from a different location, but you are limited to the locations of available proxies that support the protocol you are using.

Comment: Quite fortunately, the answer is a resounding **"no"**.

Comment: you can change your ip address to anything you want, however, that does not guarantee that you will be able to receive any network traffic for that ip address.

Comment: @jtahlborn Yes, it virtually guarantees that you would not receive any network traffic for that IP address :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** First this question has `nothing to do with Java.`

**2.** Secondly this technique is called `IP spoofing`.

**3.** Another technique is `IP hopping.`

**See this link by Cisco** :

http://www.cisco.com/web/about/ac123/ac147/archived_issues/ipj_10-4/104_ip-spoofing.html

Comment: ip spoofing only works if you don't care about receiving any return traffic.

Comment: First of all @jtahlborn this question is not about at which situation IP spoofing is possible.... Its about whether it can be done in Java or not... before downvoting an answer try to understand it.

Comment: i didn't downvote, i just commented.  i understand your answer just fine.  while the OP's question is low on details, it does seem to imply to me that the network connection still be functional (aka, can receive network traffic).  i didn't downvote your answer because the OP's question is too brief to be sure.

Comment: @jtahlborn sorry if i reacted to that, and thanks for clearing it out